# Why are polarity assigned to resistors in the circuit in questions?

Tags: circuit-analysis

I have confusion on questions that assign polarity to the resistors. Are these polarities arbitrary or are these polarities actually true? Do I have to consider these polarities while doing the circuit analysis?

For example; if I consider drop of the potential as negative, I get this equation according to assigned polarity in the question.

$$ 35-V_x-2V_x+V_0=0 $$

Also, by ohm's law, 
$$ V_x = 10*i $$
$$ V_0 = 5*i $$

This is my solution, but I don't know if it's correct or not. 
Basically, I have confusion on as to whether consider polarity as given by the question or not.

[image]

Also, this one. Are these polarities provide only to confuse students?

[image]

Comment: The + must be where the *assumed* current enters the resistor. The voltage sources are irrelevant in this respect.The problem with your diagrams is that there is no current shown.

Comment: @Chu No, it is not necessary to have an assumed direction of current before assigning a voltage polarity. We don't care about the direction of current with respect to the polarity of voltage **until** we want to use Ohm's Law or Watt's Law. Even then, we just throw in a minus sign if the assumed current doesn't enter the assumed positive voltage end.

Answer (score 2):

Assignment of polarities in typically introductory electronics questions is indeed possibly arbitrary. You want to be able to answer a question with whatever sign convention the question or schematic pose. However, when working with dependent loads/sources, the sign **is** important, as your work shows. Working clockwise around the circuit using the passive sign convention, I get the same result for your scanned circuit.

No, the polarities aren't there just to be confusing. They are there as a required sign convention and the results can be positive or negative, depending on the other circuit values. You just need to do the math using that convention.

Answer (score 2):

The polarities are important, and in this particular case the polarities are assigned specifically to see if you've been paying attention in class.

A more "normal" diagram would reverse the polarity on Vo. That way, the three voltages other than the voltage source would sum to 35. If you don't pay attention, you'll miss that and come up with a wrong result.

The intent is not to confuse students, but rather to make them entirely aware of what they are doing and what they are supposed to do. Once you define the polarities it is straightforward to write the relevant equations in such a way as to preserve those polarities.

Comment: In both the questions, one of the polarities should be reversed. But according to question, a current flowing clockwise for Vx would be a current flowing anticlockwise for Vo, which is impossible. I am still confused by the way.

Comment: @Sandeep No, you don't need to reverse any polarities. You just need to add a negation to Ohm's Law if the assumed direction of the current enters the assumed positive end of the resistor's voltage. And it's OK if some of the voltages and/or currents turn out to be negative.

Comment: @Sandeep - Eliot Alderson is correct. Try it another way: With the polarities shown, Vo is a negative voltage, while Vx is positive. Ohm's Law says that if a voltage across a resistor is negative, so is the current. That is, the direction of current flow is opposite that of a positive voltage. This is one of those things you'll just have to get used to, since when you move on to complicated circuits it may not be possible to assign positive values all around until after you've analyzed the circuit. As I said in my answer, reversing Vo makes things more obvious - so the teacher set a trap.

Answer (score 2):

What the question is trying to teach you is that the polarity affects the sign in Kirchhoff’s voltage laws, which you have correctly identified. Where you have made a mistake is in applying Ohm’s law. Remember that the polarity of the resistor voltage is opposite the current flow.

[image: resistor polarity]

[source](https://www.allaboutcircuits.com/textbook/direct-current/chpt-2/polarity-voltage-drops/)

So \$v_0 = -5i\$. The voltage is flipped, since the polarity is the reverse of what you would normally expect. If you flip the polarity, you get what you would normally expect

$$v_1 = -v_0 = 5i.$$

Comment: Oh! Thank you. Now, I understand. So, the current can be in either direction depending on the voltage value of dependent and independent voltage source, right? And, I have assumed that independent voltage source is stronger in comparison to the dependent

Comment: @Sandeep You can set the current in any direction, but you must be consistent through the circuit. Just keep in mind KCL. If there is no branching, the current must remain the same.